# Inline row vectors with smallmatrix

Tags: brackets, vector

I typeset inline column vectors with the `smallmatrix` environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
```

Unfortunately, when I do the same with row vectors I am not satisfied with the result since the height of the surrounding braces is the same as that of a column vector with two elements. Any recommendations of how to properly typeset the brackets?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I usually typeset column vectors as row vectors with the symbol of transpose attached. If you want to do with `smallmatrix`, I see no problem, as the numbers in a row vector will be normal size. How do you type a row vector?

Comment: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: I realise this isn't a direct answer to your question, but smallmatrix isn't really suitable when you only have one row. Just use `(x,y)` or maybe `(x\;y)` (or in principle `(\begin{matrix}x&y\end{matrix}`, but this seems to put in too much horizontal space for an inline equation).

Comment: If I do this it looks awkward when displayed next to a column vector typeset with smallmatrix in order to squeeze it into a line since the vector entries are of different size.

Comment: @user1225999 It does a little, but not nearly as awkward as what you're proposing, especially if it's in text that's normal size. The best overall solution is egreg's: write things like `(x,y)^\mathrm{t}(a,b)` (and only use `smallmatrix` for 2 by 2 matrices).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure you really want it, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\icol}[1]{% inline column vector
  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)%
}

\newcommand{\irow}[1]{% inline row vector
  \begin{smallmatrix}(#1)\end{smallmatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

Text $\icol{a\\b}$ text $\irow{a&b}$ text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the definition of `\irow` into

```
\newcommand{\irow}[1]{% inline row vector
  \begin{smallmatrix}(\,#1\,)\end{smallmatrix}%
}
```

then the result is

[image]

Refinements of the spacing are possible, but personally I'd go with no space.

Comment: With `mathtools` one has `smallpmatrix`.

Comment: This solution isn't quite as good as David's (or rather, looks even more bad) because the first and last entries are a bit too close to the brackets.

Comment: @Manuel `\begin{psmallmatrix}...\end{psmallmatrix}` gives a result indistinguishable from `\left(\begin{smallmatrix}...\end{smallmatrix}\right)`. Since I'm hiding this one in a macro, I won't bother.

Comment: @egreg Okey, I thought, since the `\icol` looks quite spaced, that `mathtools` might correct that.

Comment: @Manuel That's an artifact of (round) parentheses; indeed I always use (square) brackets for matrices and vectors.

Answer (score 3):

egreg will probably complain to me, but I think you are looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}




aaa $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a \\ b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
$\mathopen{\scriptstyle(}\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\end{smallmatrix}\mathclose{\scriptstyle)}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's much easier than this.

Comment: @egreg I knew you would want to verify my first statement:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I prefer this solution over egregs since it uses the spacing of the smallmatrix. However, this solution also has a weird vertical placement of the elements: Compare a&b vs. x&y.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter: the `mathtools` package defines a whole bunch of (small) matrices, with different alignments (star version). You don't have totypeset the delimiters. The case of row matrices can be managed with a special environment, with the help of the `nccmath` package. Sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

 $ \begin{psmallmatrix*}[r]a\\bcd \end{psmallmatrix*} $

 $ \begin{psmallmatrix*}[l]a\\bcd \end{psmallmatrix*} $

 $ \begin{psmallmatrix}a\\ bcd \end{psmallmatrix} $

 $ \begin{psmallmatrix}a & bdc \end{psmallmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that has the exact problem the question is asking to avoid: your image shows the brackets in the last case are the same size as in the two row matrices.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I hadn't noticed, as I focused on the simpler syntax. I've a work-around, I'll upload it in a moment.