Incompatibility of nicematrix with mdwtab
I'm using TexpadTex compiler (latex2e for what I can understand) included in Texpad editor, and when using nicematrix, I get the following error
Fatal nicematrix error: "mdwtab loaded" ! The packages 'mdwtab' and 'nicematrix' are incompatible. This error isfatal.
Nonetheless, when compiling with pdflatex I get no errors. I am also using the elsarticle class, tikz, and some colour packages.
To reproduce the error you could try the following code:
\listfiles
    \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \biboptions{sort&compress}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,nccmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \graphicspath{
            {./Figures/Diagrams/}{./Figures/Results}
        }
    \usepackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            filecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=blue
        }   
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{url}
    \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
    \usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}

    \providecommand*{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\,#1}}}
    
    \usepackage{eurosym}
    \usepackage{amstext} % for \text
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
      \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
      {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}
      
    \newcommand{\comment}[1]{}  
    \newcommand{\newpara}{\vskip 0.3cm}
    
    
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    %\makeatletter
    %\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
    %\makeatother
    %\usepackage{tablefootnote}
    
    
    \usepackage{mathtools}  
    \usepackage{xfrac} 
    
    \newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
    
    \usepackage{array}  %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335957/matrix-with-evenly-spaced-columns
    
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hbox to #1\bgroup\hss$}l<{$\egroup}}
    
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\@brcolwidth{0.67em}
    \newenvironment{brmatrix}{%
        %\left[%
        \hskip-\arraycolsep
        \new@ifnextchar[\@brarray{\@brarray[\@brcolwidth]}%
    }{%
        \endarray
        \hskip -\arraycolsep
        %\right]%
    }
    \def\@brarray[#1]{\array{r*\c@MaxMatrixCols {M{#1}}}}
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{textcomp} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/how-to-get-good-looking-copyright-and-registered-symbols
    
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624538/error-using-cedilla-ç-in-affiliation-line-with-elsarticle-class
    
    \usepackage{eqexpl}
    \eqexplSetIntro{where:} % set parenthesis in the left of the first item
    \eqexplSetDelim{=} % set delimiter to "=" %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95838/how-to-write-a-perfect-equation-parameters-description
    \eqexplSetItemAlign{l}
    
    \usepackage{multirow}
    
     \usepackage{tikz}
    %\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shapes.geometric, arrows, fit, calc, positioning, automata, snakes, backgrounds}
    
    \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric, arrows, automata, positioning, backgrounds, calc}
    
    \usepackage{makecell} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571863/how-to-split-table-header-into-2-lines
    
        %https://texblog.org/2011/04/19/highlight-table-rowscolumns-with-color/ 
        \usepackage{color, colortbl}    
        \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
        \definecolor{Red}{RGB}{255, 175, 175}
        \definecolor{Green}{RGB}{175, 255, 175}
        \definecolor{Gray}{RGB}{231,239,245}
        
        \usepackage{float}
        
        \usepackage{cuted}
        \setlength\stripsep{3 pt plus 1 pt minus 1 pt}
    \usepackage{widetext}
    \usepackage{flushend}
    
    \newcounter{mytempeqncnt}
    
    
    \newcommand{\icol}[1]{% inline column vector      %%%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200507/inline-row-vectors-with-smallmatrix
      \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right)%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\irow}[1]{% inline row vector
      \begin{smallmatrix}(#1)\end{smallmatrix}%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\icolb}[1]{% inline column vector      %%%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200507/inline-row-vectors-with-smallmatrix
      \left[\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right]%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\irowb}[1]{% inline row vector
      \begin{smallmatrix}[#1]\end{smallmatrix}%
    }
    
    
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\#\) #1} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360418/alignment-of-multlined-equations-in-algorithm
    
    \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
    
    \usepackage[short]{optidef}
    \usepackage{cleveref}


    \begin{document}
        
        \tikzset{
            ->,  % makes the edges directed
            >=stealth, % makes the arrow heads bold
            node distance=4cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if n
            every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ n
            initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
            }
            
         \tikzset{elliptic state/.style={draw,ellipse,thick, fill=gray!10}}
        
        
        \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{hey hey}
                     
        \begin{abstract}
        
        \end{abstract}
                
        \begin{keyword}
        
        \end{keyword}
        
        \end{frontmatter}
        
        
        \section{Introduction}
        
        Bla bla bla
         
        \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
            \centering % centers the figure
            \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=0.8, node distance=0cm, bend angle=20, align=center]
            \path
        
                (0,0) node[initial above, elliptic state, fill=purple!15] (D1off) {$\chi_{D1}^{\text{off}}$}
                (2.5,0) node[elliptic state, fill=teal!20] (D1on) {$\chi_{D1}^{\text{on}}$}
          
                (D1off) edge[above, bend left] node[scale=0.9]{$\sigma^{\text{accept}}_H$} (D1on)
                (D1on) edge[below, bend left] node[scale=0.9]{$\delta^{\text{full}}_{H}$} (D1off)
                (D1off) edge[above, loop left] node[scale=0.9]{$\neg \left(\,\chi_{D1}^{\text{on}} \vee \sigma^{\text{accept}}_H\right)$} (D1off)
                (D1on) edge[above, loop right] node[scale=0.9]{$\neg \left(\,\chi_{D1}^{\text{off}} \vee\delta^{\text{full}}_{H}\right)$} (D1on)
                ;
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            
                \coordinate (D1off') at ($(D1off.south west) + (-6ex,6.0ex)$);
                \coordinate (D1on') at ($(D1on.north east)+ (5ex,-4.0ex)$);
                
                 %\node (D1Control) [draw=teal!30, fit= (D1off') (D1on'), inner sep=1cm, dashed, ultra thick, fill=teal!15, fill opacity=0.2] {};
                 %\node [yshift=7ex, xshift=6ex, black] at (D1Control.west) {D1 Control};
                 
          \end{pgfonlayer}       
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Dispensers finite state machine}
            \label{fig:dipenserStateMachine}
        \end{figure}
        
        
        \begin{table}
        \centering
         \caption{Ordered paired of combinations considered for HDFV (H) and LDFV (L) refuelling availability}\label{tab:avialabilityCombinations}
                \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
                    \CodeBefore 
                      \rowcolors{3}{Gray}{}[cols={2-7}]
                      %\columncolor{white}{1}
                    \Body
                    \toprule
                     &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Second}} \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
                    \textbf{First}  & {$T_{3_1}$} & {$T_{3_2}$} & {$T_{3_3}$} & {$T_{3_4}$} & {$T_4$} & {$MEGC$}\\
                    \midrule 
                    {$T_{3_1}$} &  & H & H & H & H/L & H \\
                    {$T_{3_2}$} & H &  & H & H & H/L & H \\
                    {$T_{3_3}$} & H &  H &  & H & H/L & H \\
                    {$T_{3_4}$} & H &  H & H &  & H/L & H \\
                    %{$T_4$} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
                    %{$MEGC$} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{NiceTabular}
        \end{table}
        
        
        
        \begin{table}[h!]
         \caption{HMPC weight configuration}\label{tab:priorityWeights}
         \centering
                \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
                    \CodeBefore
                      \rowcolors{2}{white}{Gray}
                      %\columncolor{white}{1}
                    \Body
                    \toprule
                    \textbf{Weighting matrix} & \textbf{$w_p$}\\
                    \midrule
                    {$Q_{H}$} & 4 \\
                    {$Q_{L}$} & 4 \\
                    {$Q_{\text{buy}}$} & 0.8 \\
                    {$Q_{\text{sell}}$} & 1.2 \\
                    {$Q_p$} & 1.2 \\
                    {$Q_y$} & 1 \\
                    {$Q_{sft}$} & 1 \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{NiceTabular}
        \end{table}
        
        
        \section{Results and discussion}\label{sec:resultsAndDiscussion}
        
        
        \section*{Acknowledgements}
        
        
        \end{document}

The complete output log can be found at (not posted here due to length limit): output log at github
To avoid confusion, consider that Texpad editor is still called Texifier on the web, which includes the TexpadTex typesetter for local live compilation and is the source of this issue. With pdfLaTex alongside updated packages and distributions, this error does not occur.
Is there any way to unload the mdwtab package such that TexpadTex can be used with nicematrix for live compilation??

your example is incomplete (no document  environment) and uses a package not in texlive (widetext) and generates errors due to the missing \beging{document} Please fix the example so it produces the errors shown (you can presumabl edelete all the document etxt other than \begin{document} abc \end{document} and show the \listfiles ouput from the log on the two systems. Your example has \listfiles but produces no log output as there is no end document.

Unrelated but avoid doing \begin{table}[h!] h on its own usually generates warnings from latex that it is being changed to ht and ! should only be used in exceptional circumstances to over-ride the document defaults.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code does not appear to load the mdwtab package. Is that why there's no fatal error to report? Incidentally, the mdwtab package was last updated in 1998. Any particular reason for wanting to use it?

Off-topic: Instead of loading the url package and executing \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}, I suggest you load the newer xurl package.

Also off-topic: Since \textbf is a text-mode command, it shouldn't come as a surprise that it has no effect on $w_p$. Do give \boldmath $w_p$ a try instead -- or just skip the unnecessary bold-facing of all material in the header row.

@Mico I don't intend to use mdwtab at all, I believe it's being side-loaded by elsarticle class or some other package.

I appreciate the off-topic recommendations, and a complete example has been provided @DavidCarlisle

@PolCardonaRubio widetext is not a standard package, after removing that, there does not seem to be anything in the listed preamble that loads anything mdw related. Even using your proposed document content.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem, preferably without having to puzzle together multiple code blocks.

The latex version from TexpadTex seems to be rather ancient with some newer packages thrown into the mix. Looks very Frankenstein...

you are still posting disconnected fragments not a test file. If we make a test file using your preamble it still gives an error about widetext.sty not being available but otherwise does not use mdw packages. so unless your widetext.sty includes mdwtab then this file does not use that at all.

The elsarticle document class does not load the mdwtab package by default. @DavidCarlisle's answer strongly suggests that you may be using an old (and possibly misconfigured) TeX distribution which throws a spurious error message triggered by an input sanity checking routine executed by the nicematrix package. My recommendation would be to see if you can install TeXLive2024 on your system.

You should provide a more reasonable example, and show the log here not as a link to a file that may change at github however your log shows that the error is spurious and you have not loaded mdwtab
You have
! Undefined control sequence.
l.119     \IfPackageLoadedTF
                             { mdwtab }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal nicematrix error: "mdwtab loaded"
! 
! The packages 'mdwtab' and 'nicematrix' are incompatible. This error is
! fatal.
! 
! See the nicematrix documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  


So the if package load test gives an undefined command error as you have a very old expl3 with a new nicematrix package You should update the whole distribution not expect individual new packages to work on an old system.
After the first command undefined error, any further output or error message are spurious. It happens to give an error saying mdwtab is loaded but only because it failed to test for that as the test command is not defined, not because it is loaded.

You are using an old LaTeX
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>

with a contemporary expl3
Package: expl3 2017/12/16 L3 programming layer (loader) 

So you need an old release of nicematrix (the earliest nicematrix was apparently 2018 which may possibly work with your 2017 system)  or you need to update your entire latex system to 2024.

"So you need a 2017 release of nicematrix (which should have been part of your original installation)" Wasn't nicematrix only added to texlive in 2018?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ooh I suppose I should have checked, maybe that one works though, I'll reword, thanks

They use syntax from later releases, though :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i re-worded it with a "possibly" if it fails, it fails.

Good solution so nobody will blame you :P

Nice idea - dosen't work :) nicematrix needs the ! syntax from xparse, and that's not in TL'17!

I've corrected the question as indicated. I've updated to TL'24, nonetheless i don't know if TexpadTex can utilize it of how to configure it. I do want to use TexpadTex as it is the only live compiler in Texpad editor, and also is the only one I'm aware of that provides live compiling part from web-based tools. Assuming TexpadTex cannot be updated to use TL'24, a straightforward solution would be to work with everything nicematrix-related commented out to utilize TexpadTex live, and only compile with pdflatex at the end for a final version. Is anybody aware if TexpadTex can be user-configured?

I have no idea about texpad, sorry. But if it is essentially frozen to 2017 release then as you say you need to adjust packages to work for that platform, although longer term that is unlikely to be viable. @PolCardonaRubio

@PolCardonaRubio Looing at https://www.texifier.com/ios, the tool was renamed some time ago - do you have an up-to-date installation?

Yes, I'm up to date. The Texifier/texpad team seems to have some developing issues since the Windows beta has been delayed, which is sad because the editor is really good. Also, the update of their typesetter should be prioritized, as @DavidCarlisle indicates, this commenting solution is not sustainable. Thanks to everyone!
